# C# How to set affinity for just one method, apart from the rest of the program?

Tags: c#, affinity, openhardwaremonitor

I working on a small testing/monitoring tool for the CPU.
It uses an OpenHardwareMonitor and Timer to poll the system and obtain CPU temp, frequency, PPT, etc., and also can benchmark the CPU.
When I run the single-core test, I set affinity to a particular core, and this is where the problem arises.
The monitoring stalls while the core that being tested is at full load, despite the rest of the cores are idling, means, it sets the affinity for the entire program.
I use ThreadAffinity to cycle through the cores:

```
Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), new IntPtr(intptrVal));

PiTest();

Thread.EndThreadAffinity();
```

I also tried to make methods async, but it doesn't resolve the issue.
Is there any way to set a benchmark method to the particular core that is being tested right now, while allowing the rest of the program, including monitoring timer/method to use any other core?
If not, how it can be resolved in another way?

Comment: Does it help when you simply create a new thread which handle the method you want to call?

Comment: Not sure if I doing it correctly, since I have almost no experience with Thread, but I tried it this way, and the problem persist: 
Thread monitoringThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sense.ReportSystemInfo));
            monitoringThread.Start();